# how to map and compare filename in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I'm using below code to map the filename

```
function insert_data()

{

            for file in `ls -lrt Added_to_* | awk '{print $9}'`
    do
            echo "Running for File: $file"
            map_file="mapping_rule_categories.txt"
          path=`ls -lrt Added_to_* | awk '{print $9}'`
                    output=`cat $map_file | awk -F "|" -vnick="$path" '{if("$8"=="$nick") print $9}'`
    echo $output
    done
}
insert_data;
```

where **mapping_rule_categories.txt** is having mapping like

```
Removed_from_drop.rules|Disabled_in_drop.rules | Disabled_and_modified_in_drop.rules | Modified_inactive_in_drop.rules|Modified_active_in_drop.rules | Enabled_and_modified_in_drop.rules | Enabled_in_drop.rules | Added_to_drop.rules | drop.rules
```

and files in a directory are like:

```
Added_to_botcc.rules
Added_to_compromised.rules
Added_to_drop.rules
```

I need output should print filename after using map file :

```
botcc.rules
compromised.rules
drop.rules
```

Comment: Use `for file in Added_to_*; do` the `ls`, as well as the `awk` are unnecessary, slow and might cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand much of your question (tip: do something about it) but from that input to expected output:

Adding a file with a space in the name to the test dir:

```
$ touch Added_to_this\ test  # advanced test with space in filename
$ ls                         # your files and then some
Added_to_botcc.rules        Added_to_drop.rules
Added_to_compromised.rules  Added_to_this test
```

Processing the files:

```
$ for i in Added_to_* ; do echo ${i#Added_to_} ; done
botcc.rules
compromised.rules
drop.rules
this test
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shrawan - You can try below solution -

```
$cat filecomparision.sh 
function insert_data()
{
##### Looping on files in current directory to fetch only the filenames
 for file in $(ls -1rt Added_to_*) 
    do
          echo "Running for File: $file"
          map_file="mapping_rule_categories.txt"
          path=`ls -lrt Added_to_* | awk '{print $9}'`
          output=$(awk -F "|" -v nick="$file" '{gsub(/[[:space:]]/,""); if($8 ~ nick) print $9}' $map_file)
          echo "Output of file: $output"
    done
}
#######function Calling
insert_data
$ ./filecomparision.sh 
Running for File: Added_to_drop.rules
Output of file: drop.rules
Running for File: Added_to_compromised.rules
Output of file: 
Running for File: Added_to_botcc.rules
Output of file:
```